# How to auto-populate the rate/charges of a price list when quantity is entered in?

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I have a lay out of ITEM-QTY-@-CHARGE-EQUALS-$0.00. Is there a way to auto populate once the quantity is entered in the price of the item to correspond with the quantity? Example: If I choose Copy/Scan Black & White - enter qty 5 ( meaning 5 scans and copies) and that costs $0.75 per scan/copy I would want it to auto populate the price and total cost so $0.75 x 5

Answer (score 0):

### Using Cell Calculations, This is Possible

I've attached your layout as best as I understand, the heart of your question is, can I calculate the result of two cells being multiplied together.

Here's how we do it:

1. Enter The Quantity of the Item under the QTY header. Your example uses 5 so I will use 5 here.
2. Enter the Unit price under the @ header. Your example uses $.75, so we can enter .75 and press the $ up on the ribbon to have it auto-format as currency.
3. Under the CHARGE column we enter our formula. To multiply cells, we use the cell reference of where our data is to generate a result.

Enter **=B2** (The cell location of our Quantity) ***C2** (The cell location of our Unit Price). We now have **=B2*C2** by pressing enter you'll have your result, but this can be improved. By putting a $ in front of the B in B2 and C in C2, we'll haveve created an absolute reference. This means that if we auto-drag this formula somewhere else, it will always use Columns B & C as the reference. Now our formula is **=$B2*$C2** press enter and you have your result.

To make this result work without having to type out the formula everytime, select the box that contains =$B2*$C2 and click and hold on the bottom right corner of the green outline where there's a small green square. Now drag it downwards as far as you'd like and your formula will auto-populate all the cells below, automatically updating the formula for the appropriate row!

You can also drag, in the same fashion, the formula to the right and populate the equals column in the same way!

[See Attached Image!](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IU4T0.png)

Comment: that was helpful, but still a portion unanswered. I'm needing it to autopopulate the rate aka the .75 in this example or somehow lock that rate down in that particular cell so it stays there no matter the qty entered would I just =([selected cell B qty * $.75)? and have it generate in the equals cell?

Comment: So the useful thing about that formula is that it will automatically use whatever the rate for that column is when it calculates the row. For example if you were to change the unit price to .85 the calculation would change accordingly. If you'd like every price in the column to be .75, you can Copy/Paste it into the rows below, or you can do the Green Square trick when you select the cell to drag down the .75 and have it auto fill in the fields below.